# Python Library(s) for graph, plots and etc

Tags: library, python, software-development, graphs, plotting

Is there any library(s) for making a graphs and plotting and etc. for python.

It should have more no. of types of graphs and plots and etc. I'm in the idea of making a good graph plotting software using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@reducing activity's answer is good, you could also take a look at Seaborn, which is built on top of matplotlib. I find it to be pretty easy to use and the figures look really nice.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html

Answer (score 3):

For example matplotlib (I used it in https://github.com/matkoniecz/quick-beautiful/blob/master/10-nice-graphs/02_matplotlib_pchysics_examples_speed_acceleration_velocity_distance.py )

The have many supported graphs/plots, see https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html (top of list screenshoted below).

[image]

Comment: I have heard of this. Does this have a good number of types of graphs, plots and etc. Is there any modifications of this which has advantages over this? Please tell if you know it.

Comment: @SuperByte I added https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html and screenshot. Yes, they have many graphs.